# Why won't DiscretizeRegion work with a custom distance function?

Tags: regions, nearest

I am trying (in 10.0) to create a region from a list of data points.  I have created myDistance to use as the boolean test for whether or not a point should be included in the region

```
myDistance[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
  Norm[{x, y, z} - First[Nearest[pts, {x, y, z}]]]
```

where `pts` is a list of (lattice) points that I want to help define the region.  I can define a region based on this function:

```
myRegion = ImplicitRegion[myDistance[x, y, z] <= 1.01 Sqrt[3], {x, y, z}]
```

but if I try to discretize this region I get the vague error: `DiscretizeRegion::drf: DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region ImplicitRegion[<<2>>]. >>`

Any idea what is going on?

On the other hand, `RegionPlot3D[myDistance[x,y,z]<= 1.01 Sqrt[3],{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10},{z,-10,10}]` produces a perfectly fine representation of the region.

UPDATE: The problem only seems to occur for large point sets (>20 on my machine).  Smaller point sets work fine in both cases.

Comment: Try increasing `PlotPoints`. This works for me on several point sets: `DiscretizeGraphics@Normal@RegionPlot[myDistance[x, y, z] <= 1.01 Sqrt[3], , {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 30]`.

Comment: This is working so far for me for quite large point sets (assuming you mean `RegionPlot3D`...).  Why won't `DiscretizeRegion` do the same thing?

Comment: This works, too, on your specific example: `myRegion2 = RegionUnion @@ (Sphere[#, 1.01 Sqrt[3]] & /@ pts); DiscretizeRegion[myRegion2]`, but it is done without a custom distance function.

Comment: Nice!  I like that much better, and it's probably faster.  We'll see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method from another of my comments, which may work on earlier V10 versions:

```
Clear[myDistance2];
pts = RandomReal[{-8, 8}, {111, 3}];
With[{d = Nearest[pts]}, 
  myDistance2[dist_][x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
   Length@d[{x, y, z}, {1, dist}]];

DiscretizeGraphics@
  Normal@RegionPlot3D[
    myDistance2[1.01 Sqrt[3]][x, y, z] >= 1, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 
     10}, {z, -10, 10}, PlotPoints -> 30] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(I changed the distance function slightly so that it would be several times faster than the OP's.  Note also that `RegionPlot3D` does not always produce graphics with closed boundaries, even if the surface is mathematically closed.  Sometimes increasing `PlotPoints` or `MaxRecursion` can help.)

---

*Response to comment:*
@djphd `Nearest` computes a data structure that makes searching for the nearest point very efficient.  The data structure depends only on the points `pts`.  So you can save time over many queries by constructing the data structure only once.  In the first argument to `With`, the data structure is returned in the form of a `NearestFunction` returned by `Nearest`; `With` injects this function `d`  into the definition of `myDistance2`.  The form `d[point, {n, radius}]` finds the nearest `n` points within the `radius`.  It will return an empty list of length zero if there are none; otherwise, the length will be at least `1` and at most `n`.  In the definition of `myDistance2`, `n` is `1`, which gives the fastest performance.  In fact, using `Nearest[pts -> Automatic]` is a bit faster, but it does not seem to matter much in this case.

Comment: Works for 10.0 and 10.1!  Thank you!  Can you discuss a little about why using `With` and `Length` make this so much faster?  Essentially the algorithm is the same as my original effort, but this is significantly faster than I would have imagined.  Tested so far on my system with thousands of points and no problems whatsoever (especially when reducing `PlotPoints` a little because the original `pts` are so close).

Comment: @djphd To answer your question was too long for a comment, so I included it in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your code produces a perfectly good 3D region. To visualize it you just have run `DiscretizeRegion` on it.

```
SeedRandom[42];
With[{pts = RandomReal[1., {5, 3}]}, 
  inRegion[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
     Norm[{x, y, z} - First[Nearest[pts, {x, y, z}]]]]
r = ImplicitRegion[inRegion[x, y, z] <= 1.01 Sqrt[3], {x, y, z}];
dr = DiscretizeRegion[r]
```

[image: solid]

Now further computations can be done, such as

```
Volume[dr]
```

> `7.8467`

I don't know what you were expecting to see as the result of `ImplicitRegion`. The documentation makes it clear that it is a wrapper function that encapsulates region information for various region savvy functions to use.

Comment: I agree that this works, and my question has been reworded.  Your code and mine both break for more than ~20 points in `pts` on my machine.  Could it be a memory problem?

Answer (score 2):

Using regions directly is faster and works:

```
pts=RandomReal[{-8,8},{111,3}];

myRegion2=RegionUnion@@(Sphere[#,1.01 Sqrt[3]]&/@pts);
DiscretizeRegion[myRegion2]//AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice code, but it does not work on my system (10.0 or 10.1 on Windows 7).  Instead I get `{463.711, EmptyRegion[3]}` with the errors `DiscretizeRegion::drcd: Available methods not able to resolve all components of dimension 2` and `DiscretizeRegion::dre: DiscretizeRegion did not find any sample points in the region RegionUnion[<<111>>] with bounds {{-10.8139,10.8925},{-10.9602,10.9442},{-10.9636,10.9659}}. If this is not correct, different bounds may help. >>`  I have tried different bounds, different accuracy goals and different precision goals to no avail.  I don't think it's a memory issue.

Comment: @djphd The region functionality in 10.0 was not completely developed.  It's been filled in more and more with each release, 10.1, 10.2, and (I think) 10.3.  I have 10.2 currently.